# Refs Must Have Owner Warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs

I'm having this error with a RoR app (ruby 2.5, rails 5.1.4) with a react component.

**Element ref was specified as a string (name) but no owner was set. You may have multiple copies of React loaded**

The react component file:

```
var NewItem = createReactClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input ref='name'/>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

btw, I'm not using npm.

Tutorial followed from this [guide](https://github.com/pluralsight/guides/blob/master/published/ruby-ruby-on-rails/building-a-crud-interface-with-react-and-ruby-on-rails/article.md)

Comment: This the the old `ref` API. the [new API takes a function](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), the `ref` property takes a callback function, not a string.

This function receives the DOM element. E.g:

```
<input type="text" ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }} />
```

With `this.textInput` in place, you have access to the element methods, like `.focus()`, `.blur()`, etc.